# How to change size of an array during runtime in java Netbeans?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, chess

I am creating a 2-player chess game in java Netbeans (at beginner level), I wish to store the squares which can accept a piece in a JLabel Array. How can I change size of the array during runtime, because the number of squares would differ for different pieces on different locations.

Comment: Arrays have a fixed length at creation time. You could copy the array contents to a new array that is larger, or you could use a collection (like `ArrayList`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size of array is immutable, so you cannot.